# Which syntax will recomend between try and &. when we're dealing with nil value in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Like the title, from 2.3.0 ruby version. We can use Safe Navigation Operator(&.) instead of try for dealing with nil value in Rails.
But when I use the new syntax, my reviewer told that is not good for reviewer, or someone else about the meaning my code.
So I would like to know which syntax I should use when work with nil value?

```
nil.try(:method)
nil&.method
```

Comment: You should use the syntax your reviewer says you should use. It doesn't matter what *we* say if you never get your code accepted because your reviewer always rejects it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `&.` works like `#try!`, not `#try`. [documentation](http://devdocs.io/rails~5.1/object#method-i-try-21)
2. `#try` not native in ruby but it is provided by rails.
3. Safe navigation `#&.` is almost 3~4 times faster than using the `#try`

```
require 'active_support/all'
require 'benchmark'

foo = nil

puts Benchmark.measure { 10_000_000.times { foo.try(:boo) } }
puts Benchmark.measure { 10_000_000.times { foo&.boo } }
```

Output

```
      1.210000   0.000000   1.210000 (  1.211835)
      0.360000   0.000000   0.360000 (  0.363127)
```

Comment: Thanks you for detail the performance of safe navigation method.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in @dinjas's answer, `.try` is a method provided by Rails, whereas `&.` is a method that is provided by Ruby itself, and hence, will be usable outside Rails apps as well.

Additionally, the two operators do NOT work in EXACTLY the same manner. The safe navigation operator prevents `NoMethodErrors` only for those cases when it is invoked on a value which is `nil`. For example:

```
a = nil
a&.do_something # Result: nil
a = false
a&.do_something # Result: NoMethodError: undefined method `asd' for false:FalseClass

a.try(:do_something) # Result: nil
```

As seen above, while `.try` handles falsy values as well and returns `nil` as the response when a method is invoked on an object that does not support it. However, `&.` does not handle that and invokes methods on `false` as well. The same applies to blank strings.

In terms of what you should use, I believe that decision should be taken by having a discussion with your team. I believe neither of the methods are incorrect and either can be used. However, I would strongly recommend not using BOTH `try` and `&.` throughout the codebase as that could lead to unintended effects if the codebase grows large.

[This blog by Georgi Mitrev](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) describes the safe navigation operator in more depth and I would recommend giving it a read once.

Answer (score 1):

`try` is a method provided by [Rails' Active Support](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)

The safe-navigation operator is provided by [Ruby itself](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator) (since version 2.3).

If you were to open a Ruby console (not Rails), and define a method `foo`:

```
def foo
  :bar
end
```

You could see something like the following:

```
>> nil.try(:foo)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/dinjas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/dinjas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/dinjas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):7
NoMethodError (undefined method `try' for nil:NilClass)
>> nil&.foo
=> nil
```

IMHO, I prefer using Ruby methods over Rails methods as they are usable outside of the context of Rails.

That said, I also feel that whichever you use, it should be used sparingly. In my experience, it's a symptom of writing timid code (see Avdi Grimm's book, [Confident Ruby](http://www.confidentruby.com)).